# How check range beetwen to dates and make comparison in sql on ruby?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

`.joins(:residence) .where('(custom_services.date_from - ?) <= 1', Date.today)`[image: wrong attempt]

Does anyone know how to correctly  implement a check the difference between the date in custom_services.date_from and today's is less than or equal to one day(in the screenshot, one of the attempts is not correct)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just use

`.where('custom_services.date_from <= ?', Date.today + 1.day)`

Answer (score 2):

Using [`Date.tomorrow`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html#method-c-tomorrow) and beginless range:

```rb
.where(date_from: ..Date.tomorrow)
```

if need to specify table name

```rb
.where('custom_services.date_from': ..Date.tomorrow)
```

Comment: TIL about "beginless range". Wish I had noticed that on the 2.7 release notes...
Better late than never!
https://www.bigbinary.com/blog/ruby-2-7-adds-beginless-range

Answer (score 0):

Can you use something like this?

```
where("DATEDIFF(custom_services.date_from, ?) <= 1", Date.today)
```